# Data Structures in ORMs

Tags: nhibernate, data-structures, mapping

How do you map rudimentary data structures (e.g. Tree, Dictionary) in an ORM such as NHibernate.

Comment: I know how to map a tree or dictionary in NHibernate, but I don't understand your question

Comment: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/11/nhibernate-mapping-ltdynamic-componentgt.aspx

Answer (score 2):

O/R mapping is about mapping classes to tables/views so the data inside instances of both (object and table/view row) mean the same thing.

Mapping trees/dictionaries therefore doesn't make any sense, as it's not about that. If your entity is represented in code by a dictionary, THEN it makes sense, however that will never happen.